# Count lines in zipped files using Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zip, counting

There is a folder which contains more than 1000 zipped files. Each zipped file contains 12 others zipped files which contains one CSV file each. I need count the total number of lines of all files...

It can be done using windows powershell, but I am in trouble in order to unzip files, count the number of lines and zip it again, in order to save disk space during the process.

```
$folderPath="C:\_Unzip_Folder";

Get-ChildItem $folderPath -recurse | %{ 

    if($_.Name -match "^*.`.zip$")
    {
        $parent="$(Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent)";    
        write-host "Extracting $($_.FullName) to $parent"

        $arguments=@("e", "`"$($_.FullName)`"", "-o`"$($parent)`"");
        $ex = start-process -FilePath "`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe`"" -ArgumentList $arguments -wait -PassThru;

        if( $ex.ExitCode -eq 0)
        {
            write-host "Extraction successful, deleting $($_.FullName)"
            rmdir -Path $_.FullName -Force
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem $folderPath -recurse -Filter *.csv | %{ 
    Get-Content $($_.FullName)  | Measure-Object -Line
}

cmd /c pause | out-null
```

Now, it is counting lines but, it can be easier, if it SUM them to me.

Does someone can help me with this task?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try using a `foreach` loop like `foreach($file in $(gci C:\_Unzip_Folder)){if ($file.extension -eq ".csv"){foreach ($line in $(get-content $file.fullname)){$i++}}`

Comment: there is no need to re-zip the files. instead, unzip the files into a temp dir & then - when finished with them - delete the temporary unzipped files. perhaps just delete the entire temp unzip dir ... [*grin*]

Comment: @NekoMusume I didn't figure out what you tried to explain me...

Comment: See ```foreach -?```

Comment: Just add `Get-Content $($_.FullName)  | Measure-Object –Line` after instruction `Write-host "Extraction successful ....`. [Measure-Object cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7) counts a number of lines in file if you pass `-Line` parameter to it.

Comment: @krokodilkoIt works great, I changed code above, and is it possible to SUM all line count and return me the final number of lines?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Another way to do this would to do something like this `$(Get-Content $($_.FullName)).count` and the result would be the same. You could loop through the files in a folder and do `$var += $(Get-Content $($_.FullName)).count` so it adds the counts to a variable.

Comment: Full: `foreach($file in $(gci C:\_Unzip_Folder)){if ($file.extension -eq ".csv"){$var += $(Get-Content $($file.FullName)).count}}`

Answer (score 1):

You could also keep everything in memory, like this:

```bsh
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$InformationPreference = "Continue"

Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

$folderPath = "C:\_Unzip_Folder\*.zip"
$files      = Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Recurse
$csvCount   = 0
$lineCount  = 0
$bufferSize = 1MB
$buffer     = [byte[]]::new($bufferSize)

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Write-Information "Getting information from '$($file.FullName)'"

    $zip  = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($file.FullName)
    $csvs = $zip.Entries | Where-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) -eq ".csv" }
    foreach ($csv in $csvs)
    {
        $csvCount++
        Write-Information "Counting lines in '$($csv.FullName)'"

        $stream = $csv.Open()
        try
        {
            $byteCount = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize)
            while ($byteCount)
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i -lt $byteCount; $i++)
                {
                    # assume line feed (LF = 10) is the end-of-line marker
                    # you could also use carriage return (CR = 13)
                    if ($buffer[$i] -eq 10) { $lineCount++ }
                }
                $byteCount = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize)
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            $stream.Close()
        }
    }
}

Write-Information "Counted a total of $lineCount line(s) in $csvCount CSV-file(s)"
```